# Is there CSS elements that block hyphens from working?

Tags: css

I've been looking into it and can't figure it out. In my page, the hyphens that are on a *{} selector work in most places, just not the titles. And I verified, nothing comes up that undoes the *{} selector

I'm trying to figure out; is there something that blocks hyphens from working? Like how a sticky wont work if anything the sticky is over has an overflow property?

Comment: A user of your rep should know that links to other sites aren't adequate here. Please review [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a discussion on SO about this these days: The words "Navigation" and  "Databases" in your `h1` are not hyphenated because they start with a **capital letter**, which most browsers apparently interpret as not-to-be-hyphenated nouns.

You might want to spell them as "navigation" and  "databases", wrap `<span>` tags around those and apply `text-transform: capitalize`to those, either in a dedicated class or in `style` attributes. Or you use soft hyphens (`&shy;`) in those words.

Comment: That was exactly it. TIL capitalized words are ignored by hyphens.